# How can I filter the records in a CSV using bat script need to retain the header

Tags: batch-file

I have a csv file with below format

[image]

Here is the plain text format of the csv.

```
ID,FA,BA,Num,NUM#,Ser,Status,ServStatus,Code,Detail,Error,Batch
1,30000792,300007,300014651,0,BF,S,CC,53,Susp,Reason 1,Batch1
2,30000792,300007,300014679,0,WL,S,CC,53,Susp,Reason 2,Batch2
3,30000792,300007,300006632,0,MSC,B,CC,26,Base,Reason 3,Batch3
```

I need to retain the header and generate the csv by filtering the column 'Batch' based on the time, when my bat script is running.

Eg: if my script running at 10am I need to extract records with batch1

```
  @echo off
  SET /A hr =%time:~0,2%
  ECHO %hr%
  IF %hr% == 10  ( set Batch=batch1)
  IF %hr% == 12  ( set Batch=batch2)
  ECHO BATCH=%Batch%
  FindStr /I /C:"%Batch%" "input.csv">>"output.csv"
```

I'm getting below output without header

```
2,30000792,300007,300014679,0,WL,S,CC,53,Susp,Reason 2,Batch2
```

I'm new to batch script, please suggest if there is any better way to check the hour.

Comment: First of all the image you have shown is not of a CSV, it appears to be an image showing how your CSV is traslated and shown in a specific software application. What we expect you to do is to open up the CSV file in a plain text editior, copy its content, and paste it into your question, formatting it as code. Then we expect you to post the code you have written to attempt the task you're trying to achieve, but which is faling to do so. Along with that you should include debugging and other pertinent information. Please take the [tour], and read through all of the pages of [ask] before editing

Comment: Some information on how to translate the time to a number might be helpful. As your question is stated now, it's like `if %time% == 10:00:00,00 then <filter for "batch1">`. I guess we can agree that's not what you want.

Comment: Hint: You are allowed to use multiple `/C` options with the `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: Try `FindStr /IE ",%Batch% ,Batch" "input.csv"`

Comment: To reliably get a date/time string (or a portion of it) see [this list of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format?r=SearchResults&s=1|160.9734)

Comment: Hi All Thanks for the input.
I manage to get the expected result by using Multiple `/C` with `FINDSTR` as @Squashman suggested.